# npm install -g windows-build-tools is giving me errors even after running as administrator

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I am trying to follow: https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejs-guidelines/blob/master/windows-environment.md#compiling-native-addon-modules

I am running Windows PowerShell as an administrator and I get this:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> npm install -g windows-build-tools
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated windows-build-tools@5.2.2: Node.js now includes build tools for Windows. You probably no longer need this tool. See https://github.com/felixrieseberg/windows-build-tools for details.
npm WARN cleanup Failed to remove some directories [
npm WARN cleanup   [
npm WARN cleanup     'C:\\Users\\seany\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\windows-build-tools',
npm WARN cleanup     [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir 'C:\Users\seany\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\windows-build-tools\node_modules\uri-js\dist'] {
npm WARN cleanup       errno: -4048,
npm WARN cleanup       code: 'EPERM',
npm WARN cleanup       syscall: 'rmdir',
npm WARN cleanup       path: 'C:\\Users\\seany\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\windows-build-tools\\node_modules\\uri-js\\dist'
npm WARN cleanup     }
npm WARN cleanup   ]
npm WARN cleanup ]
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\seany\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\windows-build-tools
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node ./dist/index.js
Downloading python-2.7.15.amd64.msi
npm ERR! [============================================>] 100.0% (0 B/s)
npm ERR! Downloaded python-2.7.15.amd64.msi. Saved to C:\Users\seany\.windows-build-tools\python-2.7.15.amd64.msi.
Downloading vs_BuildTools.exe
npm ERR! [============================================>] 100.0% (0 B/s)
npm ERR! Downloaded vs_BuildTools.exe. Saved to C:\Users\seany\.windows-build-tools\vs_BuildTools.exe.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Starting installation...
npm ERR! Downloading installers failed. Error: TypeError: 'process.env' only accepts a configurable, writable, and enumerable data descriptor
npm ERR!     at Function.defineProperty (<anonymous>)
npm ERR!     at Object.removePath (C:\Users\seany\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\windows-build-tools\dist\utils\remove-path.js:11:12)
npm ERR!     at Object.install (C:\Users\seany\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\windows-build-tools\dist\install\index.js:29:19)
npm ERR!     at C:\Users\seany\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\windows-build-tools\dist\start.js:17:19
npm ERR!     at Object.download (C:\Users\seany\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\windows-build-tools\dist\download.js:35:5)
npm ERR!     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
npm ERR!     at async Object.aquireInstallers (C:\Users\seany\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\windows-build-tools\dist\aquire-installers.js:32:13) {
npm ERR!   code: 'ERR_INVALID_OBJECT_DEFINE_PROPERTY'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! windows-build-tools will now exit.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\seany\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-12-15T21_59_38_918Z-debug-0.log
```

I even tried Option 2 and I get:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> npm config set python python2.7
npm ERR! `python` is not a valid npm option
```

Python2.7 is the only python I have installed too.

Lastly I have tried following this: https://github.com/felixrieseberg/windows-build-tools

I still receive errors:

```
PS C:\Users\seany> npm install --global windows-build-tools
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated windows-build-tools@5.2.2: Node.js now includes build tools for Windows. You probably no longer need this tool. See https://github.com/felixrieseberg/windows-build-tools for details.
npm WARN cleanup Failed to remove some directories [
npm WARN cleanup   [
npm WARN cleanup     'C:\\Users\\seany\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\windows-build-tools',
npm WARN cleanup     [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir 'C:\Users\seany\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\windows-build-tools\node_modules\verror\node_modules'] {
npm WARN cleanup       errno: -4048,
npm WARN cleanup       code: 'EPERM',
npm WARN cleanup       syscall: 'rmdir',
npm WARN cleanup       path: 'C:\\Users\\seany\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\windows-build-tools\\node_modules\\verror\\node_modules'
npm WARN cleanup     }
npm WARN cleanup   ]
npm WARN cleanup ]
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\seany\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\windows-build-tools
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node ./dist/index.js
Downloading python-2.7.15.amd64.msi
npm ERR! [============================================>] 100.0% (0 B/s)
npm ERR! Downloaded python-2.7.15.amd64.msi. Saved to C:\Users\seany\.windows-build-tools\python-2.7.15.amd64.msi.
Downloading vs_BuildTools.exe
npm ERR! [============================================>] 100.0% (0 B/s)
npm ERR! Downloaded vs_BuildTools.exe. Saved to C:\Users\seany\.windows-build-tools\vs_BuildTools.exe.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Starting installation...
npm ERR! Downloading installers failed. Error: TypeError: 'process.env' only accepts a configurable, writable, and enumerable data descriptor
npm ERR!     at Function.defineProperty (<anonymous>)
npm ERR!     at Object.removePath (C:\Users\seany\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\windows-build-tools\dist\utils\remove-path.js:11:12)
npm ERR!     at Object.install (C:\Users\seany\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\windows-build-tools\dist\install\index.js:29:19)
npm ERR!     at C:\Users\seany\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\windows-build-tools\dist\start.js:17:19
npm ERR!     at Object.download (C:\Users\seany\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\windows-build-tools\dist\download.js:35:5)
npm ERR!     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
npm ERR!     at async Object.aquireInstallers (C:\Users\seany\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\windows-build-tools\dist\aquire-installers.js:32:13) {
npm ERR!   code: 'ERR_INVALID_OBJECT_DEFINE_PROPERTY'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! windows-build-tools will now exit.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\seany\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-12-15T22_09_51_000Z-debug-0.log
```

Answer (score -3):

Read this:

https://github.com/felixrieseberg/windows-build-tools/issues/20

the solution is more related to windows runtime that you missed, follow instruction.

Comment: "read this" with a link and no real explanation... what happens  when that link dies? This is why people are downvoting you.